# Authorize.Net CIM, After saving detail in hosted popup form, need to call my custom JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, authorize.net, authorize.net-cim

When I save payment detail in CIM hosted popup form after saving data massage display like
*'your information has been saved'*, I need to call at that time my java-script function, Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

This JavaScript should do the trick:

```
AuthorizeNetPopup.options.onPopupClosed = function() {
    // your JavaScript code here
};
```

Comment: hey, this is work when iframe close, I need when payment detail save successfully,